# Why are my Discord Assets not saving after Upload?

Tags: save, discord

I wanted my own Rich Presence but when I uploaded the Large and Small Image Key and pressed save, it didn't save after I switched back to other settings.

Thanks for Answers!

Comment: Hi! That is some kind of bug, i fixed it removing/updating the app icon in general information. Hope it works for you.